# Trying to perform quartile analysis with a dynamic range

Tags: excel, offset

I'm performing quartile analysis to observe trends in student performance. Up to now, I have used the following set of formulas to achieve this...but these all require manual updating and i desire to increase my efficiency since i update this monthly/quarterly. I'm using "gpa" to represent the range of data, but it is a static range currently.

`=quartile.exc(gpa,quartile number)` to establish the bins

e.g `1Q=0-3.08, 2Q=3.09-3.33, ETC`

then i run my data through the quartiles using `countifs` to determine the number and percentage of students that fall into each quartile after comparing to a relevant baseline where c5 and c6 etc are the values associated with the upper limit of each quartile

```
=countifs(gpa,">"&$c5,gpa,"<=",&$c6)
```

I've recently updated to storing my data in a data table to allow the autonomous updating of the previous static ranges (represented by gpa). I also throw in additional criteria to get different slices of data (e.g. FY 19, FY 20 etc).

Current Challenge:  I want my spreadsheet to automatically update and return running results of the last quarter and year worth of data. I created the following dynamic range.

dynamic range...=offset(header, counta(gpa column), 0,-200,1)

I tested the validity of my dynamic range using =average(dynamic range) and =countif(dynamic range,"<>") and returned correct results.  Average function was checked with manual selection of last 200 gpa cells and countif returned 200, as it should.

I attempted inserting this dynamic range into my countifs function above for the quartile analysis and got #Value!...

=countifs(gpa,">"&$c5,gpa,"<=",&$c6, dynamic range, "<>")

I do not understand why the function fails. This function should return the number of times a gpa value falls between the two numbers (c5,c6) and is within the dynamic range.

Any alternate solutions are welcome. I unfortunately cannot provide my spreadsheet as it is on a secure network.

Comment: `COUNTIFS` requires that all ranges be of the same size (and orientation). In your formula, that is unlikely

Answer (score 0):

In your formula, your `COUNTIF` ranges are not all the same size. In particular, `gpa` and `dynamicrange` are probably different sizes, hence the error.

Because of how you define `dynamicRange`, the following should be equivalent:

```
=COUNTIFS(dynamicRange,">="&$C5,dynamicRange,"<="&$C6)
```

---

To replicate your original formula (in the event you redefine `dynamicRange` so that it is not always completely contained within `gpa`):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly --

- Return a count of all the numbers in `gpa` that

  - are `=>` the value in `C5`, and
  - are `<=` the value in `C6`, and
  - are also included in `dynamicrange`

then the following formula should work:

```
=SUM(ISNUMBER(MATCH(gpa,dynamicRange,0))*(gpa>=$C5)*(gpa<=$C6))
```